# Is it a good pratice to reference a NFT by its IPNS link?

Tags: dapps, nft, ipfs

So I was wondering if it is actually a good practice for one to use an IPNS link from the IPNS protocol as a mean to point for a NFT? 
The need for the IPNS link instead of the normal IPFS link is related to some mutability that the content stored in the IPFS protocol would need from times to times, with the IPNS link I could always have the same IPNS link no matter the changes on the file associated with this link. 
Is there a better approach to it?